# how can i set document.cookie in ajax?

Tags: authentication, cookies, xmlhttprequest, request-headers, http-options-method

the error i get

```
OPTIONS https://page/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and the reason i do need to use a `RequestHeader("Cookies", "test");`

> Login Failure: Browser did not support Cookie. Please enable Cookie.

what can i do to get around this ? like how does the browser send a header while options isn't allowed ? sending a get request before the post request didn't help because there wasn't any response cookies .

some lines from [the page source code](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d372b2479402)  that i think are important .

```
var strCookie = document.cookie;
document.cookie = cookie;
var cookie = "Language=en" + expires + "; 
var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
```

even when i bypassed that error by running the code in the page console chrome tab ... still

> Please enable Cookie

so i tried

```
 var cookie = "Language=en"
document.cookie = cookie;
```

and it worked but in the js file it didn't even

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

returns empty !
the full code

```
var cookie = "Language=en"
document.cookie = cookie;
console.log(document.cookie)
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open("post", 'https://page', false);
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr1.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr1.status === 200) {
var cookie = "Language=en"
document.cookie = cookie;
console.log(document.cookie)
}
}
xhr1.send("Username=test&Password=test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script must run on the same url/ip that you want to set the cookies on … you can’t set cookies for other sites simply using `document.cookie = "cookie";`
maybe [using something like this](https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/rebinder.html) you can have two different ips in one url